# Making an extended Battery Pack + Charger for a Tablet PC

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, battery-charging

I want to make a battery pack with mains charger to power my tablet that has a wonky battery.  It lasts all day if I do not use WiFi, but with WiFi it dies within the hour.

I have 4 Nokia BL-5C 3.7 V 1000 mAh and 2 Nokia BL-6C 5v 1000 mAh batteries (but no way of charging them.

Is there a way of using either of the batteries I have (in series?) and make a circuit to charge them while still connected to the tablet via its DC in?

I was told at Uni by a techie, that I need to make a charging unit, but has a "step down" out put to the DC in of the tablet.   In theory it could charge and supply power at the same time, but with a switching circuit would act as a plain battery?

Comment: I'm handy with a soldering iron, so a simple schematic / diagram is OK ;)

Comment: got a battery spec and tablet P/N?

Comment: Hi Richman, All I know is.. 

The 4x BL-5C 3.7v 1000mAh. Pinouts are + O – 
Type lithium-ion, 3.7V Capacity:1000mAh/1200mAH Max Charge Voltage:4.2V

The 2x Nokia BL-6C 5v 1000 mAh. Pinouts are + - O 
Type lithium-ion, 3.7V Capacity:1000mAh/1200mAH Max Charge Voltage:4.2V

The Tablet is a MID-2910 and takes 5v 1000 – 1500mAh

Cheers John

Comment: Have I asked the impossible? Or is this project feasible?

Comment: it might be more feasible to find a laptop battery/charger pair on surplus then add a 5V converter output with a 5 day capacity. Or simply buy a replacement.

Comment: Thanks Richman, that might be an idea, as the Tablet is a sealed unit, and can't be taken apart without breaking the outer case (or more lightly the screen) in the process.  I have had several people look at the tablet, all say the same, can't open without breaking it :( It seemed that as I have these 6 new Nokia batteries, it would of been nice to use them.  It was just the Techie at the Uni said about a switching/pass-through charger, with either the two 5v batteries or the four 3.7v in series, with a stepped down out put to 5v 1000mAh.. And I got my hopes up LoL. Cheers John

Comment: If you like to experiment, this chip with/(without 0.5A) an external transistor can be reconfigured to step up and step down http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mc33063a.pdf

Comment: Thanks Again Richman, I will check it out, just hope my circuity is up to the job ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to charge cellphone batteries in parallel. This is not a safe thing to do.
You would not get much energy out from it either.

If you want to build an external battery I would suggest building it from 18650 cells. You do always need to be careful when working withing lithium batteries, so if you thing that you might not know what you are doing, then don't do it and buy a ready-made battery pack instead.